# How to extract data from a Google geocode JSON response

Tags: json

I'm trying to access data from a JSON response returned by the Google geocode feature. How do I access the postcode 'L13' (long_name from the address_components section) in the following JSON

My best effort so far is below (which outputs an array);

```
$address = 'Old Swan';    
$coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&region=gb');
$coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);
echo $coordinates->results[0]->address_components;
```

JSON response;

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Old Swan",
               "short_name" : "Old Swan",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Liverpool",
               "short_name" : "Liverpool",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Liverpool",
               "short_name" : "Liverpool",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Liverpool",
               "short_name" : "Liverpool",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Merseyside",
               "short_name" : "Mersyd",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "England",
               "short_name" : "England",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "L13",
               "short_name" : "L13",
               "types" : [ "postal_code_prefix", "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Old Swan, Liverpool, Liverpool, Merseyside L13, UK",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 53.41419399999999,
               "lng" : -2.907765
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 53.42084389999999,
                  "lng" : -2.8917576
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 53.407543,
                  "lng" : -2.9237724
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJW3JtBYUhe0gRDTIY8Lot-_I",
         "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array search to find the chosen array;

PHP has a function that allows to you seek through arrays

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

This is an example

```
$result = array_search("L3", array_column($coordinates->results[0]->address_components, 'long_name'));
```

Comment: The problem is, the post code varies, it isn't always 'L13'?

Comment: @MichaelLB is there anything that is fixed?

Comment: @MichaelLB like anything that doesn't change?

Comment: The 'types' values stay the same.